# What does it mean for a control to be Unicode or ANSI?

Tags: winapi, unicode, ansi

Windows controls can be Unicode or ANSI, my question is what does it mean for a control to be in one of these two categories?

Is it the following (if I assume that the control is Unicode):

- The buffer for the control is in Unicode.
- WM_CHAR messages are sent as Unicode (e.g. 'A' is sent as 0x0041 and not as 0x41).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the buffer for the control", but I think I give a comprehensive explanation anyway.

Comment: I mean the memory allocated to hold the control data, for example the "EDIT" control buffer holds the string that will be painted in the control. So if the control is Unicode then the buffer will be considered to be Unicode (every 2 bytes will be mapped to 1 character).

Comment: This "buffer" has nothing to do with whether the window is Unicode or not. The buffer you're talking about is internal to the control, abstracted from the concept of a window being Unicode. A window being Unicode is only about the messages being passed into its window proc. What the control then does with that data is a black box. I cover the case of `WM_SETTEXT` in my answer, which I think is what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So in theory even if I had an ANSI "EDIT" control, I shouldn't assume that the string in memory would be represented as 1 byte for each character, and Windows is free to represent it however it wants (maybe 4 bytes for each character!). Is my assumption correct? or should I investigate more into this issue before asking anymore questions?

Comment: I added a whole section about common controls & parents to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the window messages sent to the window procedure will be the ANSI or Unicode versions. For example a Unicode window will receive a [`CREATESTRUCTW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632603(v=vs.85).aspx) in `WM_CREATE`, while the ANSI windows will receive a `CREATESTRUCTA`.

This will apply to almost every window message containing string data.

Windows will internally marshal data accordingly. For example if you call the ANSI `SendMessageA(WM_SETTEXT, ...)` to a Unicode window, the window will receive [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx) with a Unicode string.

A window will be Unicode or ANSI depending on whether its class was registered with [`RegisterClassExA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`RegisterClassExW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx). You can test if a window is Unicode or not by calling [`IsWindowUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

Some info about common controls, because that seems to be what you're talking about.

First of all, there is no problem with an ANSI window being the parent of a Unicode window. Also keep in mind that "controls" are just windows.

Common controls are *always* Unicode. The messages they receive will be in the native, Unicode, format. Of course you won't have visibility to this because it's all internal to the OS (exception: if you subclass a common control).

The messages you are typically dealing with will be sent to your window in the form of `WM_COMMAND` or [`WM_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx). These messages are sent from common controls to their parent window (your window). They will respect your window being Unicode or ANSI like this:

1. First they will send your window a [`WM_NOTIFYFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775584(v=vs.85).aspx) message to ask if you prefer messages to be received in ANSI or Unicode (despite your window being Unicode or ANSI).
2. If you don't handle WM_NOTIFYFORMAT, then the control will call `IsWindowUnicode` to determine.
3. Then the control will send the message accordingly.

So basically, you never need to know if a common control is Unicode or not, because 1) it always is, and 2) this question is only relevant as a matter of handling messages, which is internal to Windows, not your responsibility.

Your responsibility is to handle notifications coming *from* common controls *to* your own window. In this case the Unicode/ANSI-ness of your own window is all that matters.

Comment: The data for `WM_SETTEXT` is indeed marshaled. The example you give, however, illustrates data **conversion**. Maybe you can update the answer to explain each concept individually. An additional note on `WM_NOTIFY` that explains, why there is a need for `WM_NOTIFYFORMAT` (notifications are sent to a control's parent) would further improve an already good answer.

Comment: This is NOT entirely correct! Windows doesn't do any marshalling of the correct encoding for you. If it's ANSI control and you query it as if it was wide char, you will get disappointed to get garbage. An example of that is RichText v2 control, with its RichText20A and RichText20W versions, where in order to obtain the text, you need to pass the correct ANSI or WIDE char structure TEXTRANGEA / TEXTRANGEW. If you send TEXTRANGEA to RichText20W, you will get garbage or nothing, same the other way round.